# laravel 5.4 - php artisan migrate command doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have four migrations file and when I run `php artisan migrate` in the command line it says:

`Nothing to migrate`

I also tried with `php artisan migrate --database=vcp`:

`Database [vcp] not configured.`

I used another database in my `.env` file and ran `php artisan migrate` command again:

```
Migration table created successfully.
Nothing to migrate.
```

running

`php artisan migrate:refresh`, `php artisan migrate:reset`, `php artisan migrate:status`, `php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations/migration_file"` whit these messages

```
Nothing to rollback.
Nothing to migrate.
No migrations found
```

and

```
composer dump-autoload or composer update
```

didn't help.

here is my `.env` file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=vcp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

my `2017_05_10_201750_add_columns_to_users.php`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddColumnsToUsers extends Migration
   {
       /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
        */
       public function up()
      {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->string('status')->default('online');
                $table->string('api_token');
           });
       }

     /**
      * Reverse the migrations.
      *
      * @return void
     */
    public function down()
     {
         Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('status');
            $table->dropColumn('api_token');
        });
     }
}
```

please help!

Comment: What do your mirgation files look like and what have you named them?

Comment: **I changed my database and ran php artisan migrate command again:** The changes are done in migration file or directly on database?

Comment: I created them with `php artisan make:migration create_name_of_table`

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan migrate --path="database/migrations"`?

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz directly on database, nothing exists in database except migrations table and my migrations table is empty!

Comment: @Ian it says `Nothing to migrate.
`

Comment: Can you try `php artisan migrate --path=database/migrations -vvv` could you also post your migrations?

Comment: @Erfan check the below answer. May be that can help you

Comment: @Ian still says `Nothing to migrate.` I edit the post and add one of my migrations, I wanna add two columns to my users table but I can't migrate it. Even the other migration files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me:

First, delete all your database tables including the migrations table.
Second, the update method up() of your AddColumnsToUsers file like this:

```
public function up()
    {
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {

        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('status')->default('online');
            $table->string('api_token');
       });

    DB::commit();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        DB::rollBack();
        $this->down();
    }
}
```

This checks your database to see if table already exists, it creates the table if it doesn't exist and rollbacks if it does.
Let me know if this worked.

Answer (score 3):

As you have already stated in above comments, `The changes are done directly on database`. Then `Nothing to migrate.` is correct.

Try to understand the concept, migration contains the table structure in files and when you run migration these tables are created in database. When ever you make changes in migration file, you have to again run the migration so that these changes are reflected back to database table. So the flow is:

```
migration file -> database table
```

not

```
database table -> migration file
```

Comment: I understand the concept, thanks! but I don't know where is wrong with my code. still I can't migrate my migration files !

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you write your *Migration* function by hand, as I do, copying and pasting an old one, and changing the filename by hand.
Ex:
the file 2021_10_13_082805_**insert_fields_pages_table**.php
If this is the same situation, take care to the class name, it must contain a name that reflects the filename.
In this example:

```
class InsertFieldsPagesTable extends Migration
```

If you forget to change the class name, migrations says nothing and do nothing.